# javascript appending in a for loop not working but alering is

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to append to a string in a for loop.  I can alert each value bieng looped but i cant append for some reason:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function doIt(){
                    var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
                    var css="";
                    for (i=0; i<=styleSheet.cssRules.length; i++)
                    {
                        css += styleSheet.cssRules[i].cssText;
                        //alert(styleSheet.cssRules[i].cssText); //WORKS
                    }
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container{display:none;}
            .markup-container{color:#404040;}
            .title{text:decoration:underline;}
            .body{color:#000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" onmousedown="doIt()">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="markup-container">
                <div class="title">This is a title with some markup</div>
                <div class="body">This is the body with some markup and it's longer ^^</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "can't append", what does that mean? The string is still empty? You might want to try calling toString() on the cssText, though you shouldn't have to.

Comment: I can do something like `css += "somestring";` and that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is off by one :)

```
for (i=0; i<=styleSheet.cssRules.length; i++)
//should be:
for (i=0; i<styleSheet.cssRules.length; i++)
```

When this happens at the end:

```
styleSheet.cssRules[styleSheet.cssRules.length].cssText
```

You'll get an error, because you're one past the length of the array, and `styleSheet.cssRules[i]` is `undefined`, resulting in an error when you try to access the `.cssText` property on it.